# ColdFusion - HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Tags: coldfusion, webserver, iis-8.5, coldfusion-11

I just installed ColdFusion 11 Developer edition on Windows 8.1 with IIS 8.5 as an external web server for ColdFusion. Installation succeeded but when I click on the ColdFusion Administrator I get the following error:
[image]

On windows explorer I noticed that the directory C:\ColdFusion11\cfusion\wwwroot does not exist. So, I ran the ColdFusion Web Server Configuration Tool using the instructions [here](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Web+Server+Management#WebServerManagement-Webserverconfiguration) and [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Installing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cdec18a15-7ffb.html). But I still don’t see the above directory. How can the above error be resolved?

**EDIT**
In IIS when I click on the virtual directory CFIDE created by the ColdFusion installation (or CF Web Configuration tool), I get the following error:
[image]

Comment: Can you run the webserver connector tool (as administrator) and recreate the connecor

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you create  a test site and place a test html and a test cfm page.
2. Now, browse to the html page and it should render in the browser.
3. Now create a connector to the site and access the test html and test cfm page
4. If you get error 500, then ensure the bitness of both CF and IIS are same.
5. Else, if you get error 500.19 or any other, please ensure that you have permissions on \ColdFusion11\config\wsconfig\

Comment: How can I create a test site since the virtual directory folder was not created by the installation. I've added an EDIT section at the end of my original post.

Comment: Does the physical location C:\ColdFusion11\cfusion\wwwroot exist?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. No. It does not exist. It seems the installation (or maybe the ColdFusion Web Configuration tool) created virtual directory CFIDE but not its physical location.

Comment: Where did you install CF then? Just navigate to \ColdFusion11\cfusion\runtime\bin\ and run the wsconfig.exe

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your configurations are incorrect. Check to confirm that the IIS handler mapping for each of the ColdFusion extensions matches with what is in the applicationHost.config file (found in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config).

Did you have an existing installation of ColdFusion 10? If yes, maybe you should configure to a specific site during install of CF11, but choose an IIS site that is not connected to CF10.

Would be helpful to know what you chose for the configure web servers/websites. Did you select All IIS websites or Configure specific IIS website?

Maybe it's quicker to uninstall and reinstall ColdFusion 11 from scratch, then check to ensure that the IIS handler mappings for the ColdFusion extensions are correct (i.e. points to its correct physical where CF11 was installed).

Sometimes the installer doesn't update the IIS handler mapping correctly. So you will need to manually check each one and update accordingly.